# MySQL and ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I was looking for any results that show the difference between MYSQL FULL TEXT search and ELASTIC SEARCH.

Which one is quicker?

Has someone already used it in huge databases?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [tour] and [ask] then edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- MySQL and ES has totally different ideas behind data storages. ES gives you more control
- Generally speaking, ES is faster for fulltext
- More important, ES was built for scaling, MySQL wasn't. Idk what do you mean by "huge databases", but in modern world, "huge" in most cases mean that you cant fit data into single average hardware node => you need horizontal scaling. Scaling MySQL is nightmare, as it fits the CA points of [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), ES made for AP
- ES is production-ready/proven solution for fulltext search and analytics. Can't say the same about fulltext storages in MySQL